# "You don't have another device" when trying to install Android apps on ChromeOS

Tags: google-play-store, installation, chrome-os

This is a weird situation: since I don't have a smartphone, I installed PrimeOS on a USB stick and booted on a laptop. Under this live system, I installed some apps in Google Play Store just to test them (the laptop is recognized as a mobile device).

Afterward, I decided to overwrite the USB stick with ChromeOS. Now under ChromeOS, the Play Store shows my installed apps, but of course, I cannot access them anymore. It seems impossible to delete them or install them again. The Play Store says, "You don't have another device".

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: PlaySore can not know the other "device" running PrimeOS because it doesn't exist anymore. From PlayStore perspective the installed OS is the device not the physical device.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Sorry, I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Do you actually want to have the Android app on ChromeOS? Otherwise, you might have to resort to dual boot or use an Android emulator.

Comment: Yes, I want to use them under ChromeOS. In the past, I had bad luck with android-x86 (neither wifi nor lan worked).

Comment: If it's okay, could you mention the app you want to install? It seems the app is incompatible with ChromeOS and thus it cannot be installed, but without knowing the details, it's only a wild guess.

Comment: @AndrewT. I don't think that is the problem. It happens with every app, including Telegram or the official app from my bank.

Comment: Fair point, but I still think the relation to PrimeOS is tangential as Robert has explained. Instead, this looks like a question on how to install Android apps on your laptop running ChromeOS. I have to admit that I don't have experience with ChromeOS, but I learned that [not all Android apps are supported on ChromeOS](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/7021273) and even more, [ChromeOS Flex doesn't support Android apps](https://screenrant.com/use-android-app-chrome-os-flex-can/), thus probably back to the alternative of dual boot or using Android emulator.

Comment: Yes, it is probably not related to PrimeOS. Given that I run ChromeOS as a live-system, I'm pretty sure the same problem arises from different boots from the usb stick (I may try this later). The actual problem is that the play-store tries to book-keep my installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew T. pointed out in the comments, ChromeOS Flex (which I'm actually running) does officially NOT support Android apps.